# JavaScript - connect four - Winner is - getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have made the game Connect four. 
When i use an alert to show the winner, the alert box pops up before the last piece is placed. Therefore i would like to use the DOM to announce the winner.

I have made a `<div id="winPlayer1">Red Wins!</div>` in HTML

And my JS looks like this:

```
function gameOver() {

    if (activePlayer == 0) {
        document.getElementById("winPlayer1").innerHTML;
    } else {
        pdocument.getElementById("winPlayer2").innerHTML;
    }
    gameActive = false;
}
```

How do i get the message to pop up when there is a winner?

Now they are both shown on the page even when there is no winner.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that question. The problem here is 1.  `document.getElementById("winPlayer1").innerHTML;` does absolutely nothing and 2. there's a typo `pdocument` which will cause an error.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo Chris.
What am i missing for this to work ?

Comment: Here's your code as you intended it I guess (display one of two divs): https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/od4x1037/ Here's another version (set text of single div): https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/bjy754cp/

Comment: Thanks a lot! @ChrisG